# Postgres Copy select rows from CSV table

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, postgresql-9.3, import-from-csv

This is my first post to stackoverflow. Your forum has been SO very helpful as I've been learning Python and Postgres on the fly for the last 6 months, that I haven't needed to post yet. But this task is tripping me up and I figure I need to start earning reputation points:

I am creating a python script for backing up data into an SQL database daily. I have a CSV file with an entire months worth of hourly data, but I only want to select a single day of data from from the file and copy those select rows into my database. Am I able to query the CSV table and append the query results into my database? For example:

```
        sys.stdin = open('file.csv', 'r')    
        cur.copy_expert("COPY table FROM STDIN 
                         SELECT 'yyyymmddpst LIKE 20140131' 
                         WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER", sys.stdin)
```

This code and other variations aren't working out - I keep getting syntax errors. Can anyone help me out with this task? Thanks!!

Comment: "I keep getting syntax errors". And the **exact text** of those errors is.... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need create temporary table at first:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "temp_table" (LIKE "your_table") WITH OIDS')
```

Than copy data from csv:

```
cur.execute("COPY temp_table FROM '/full/path/to/file.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','")
```

Insert necessary records:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO your_table SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE yyyymmddpst LIKE 20140131")
```

And don't forget do `conn.commit()`
Temp table will destroy after `cur.close()`

Comment: Your second line isn't quite right, as the user is `COPY`ing from the client side. They need to use `psycpg2`'s `copy_from`. Otherwise that's right. You can also specify `ON COMMIT DROP` to have the temp table vanish at `commit` time, btw.

Comment: @Dmitry I changed the cur.execute in your second line to cur.copy_expert and it worked. I kept getting stuck on file permissions and "\COPY..." doesn't work for python syntax. But cur.copy_expert works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can `COPY (SELECT ...) TO` an external file, because PostgreSQL just has to read the rows from the query and send them to the client.

The reverse is not true. You can't `COPY (SELECT ....) FROM ...`  . If it were a simple `SELECT` PostgreSQL could try to pretend it was a view, but really it doesn't make much sense, and in any case it'd apply to the *target* table, not the *source* rows. So the code you wrote wouldn't do what you think it does, even if it worked.

In this case you can create an `unlogged` or `temporary` table, copy the full CSV to it, and then use SQL to extract just the rows you want, as pointed out by Dmitry.

An alternative is to use [the `file_fdw`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) to map the CSV file as a table. The CSV isn't copied, it's just read on demand. This lets you skip the temporary table step.

Comment: I like the idea of using file_fdw, but curious if I'm able to: `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE temp (LIKE existing_DB)`? As opposed to listing all the column names again. I tried the `LIKE` option but got: `Error: LIKE is not supported for creating foreign tables`

Answer (score 0):

From PostgreSQL 12 you can add a `WHERE` clause to your `COPY` statement and you will get only the rows that match the condition.
So your `COPY` statement could look like:

```
COPY table 
 FROM '/full/path/to/file.csv' 
 WITH( FORMAT CSV, HEADER, DELIMITER ',' )
 WHERE yyyymmddpst LIKE 20140131
```